# Sum of integers in the multidimensional list with recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

Calculating the sum of integers contained in the multidimensional list in python with recursion.

```
list = [1, 8, [6, 4, 8, 9] 1, [4, 6, 9, 0], 5, 6]

def listsum(numList):
   if len(numList) == 1:
        return numList[0]
   else:
        return numList[0] + listsum(numList[1:])

print(listsum(list))
```

Im sure a problem is in multidimensional list. How fix code?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking because there is not even a question mark in this post. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Well, that can easily be done with a simpler recursive function:

```
def sum_it(l):
  if (isinstance(l, int)):
    return l
  elif (isinstance(l, list)):
    return sum(sum_it(elm) for elm in l)
```

**Highlights**:
1. [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is used for type checking.
2. [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) sums the elements of a given iterable

**Edit:**
If you are not allowed to use `sum`, a `for` loop can be used too:

```
def sum_it(l):
  if (isinstance(l, int)):
    return l
  elif (isinstance(l, list)):
    res = 0
    for elm in l:
      res += sum_it(elm)
    return  res
```

**EDIT 2:**
If for some ludicrous reason you are not even allowed to use `isinstance`, you may use exception handling, **but I'd recommend against it** since it makes the whole thing less readable and more messy than it is has to be:

```
def sum_it(l):
  try:
    res = 0
    for elm in l:
      res += sum_it(elm)
    return  res
  except TypeError:
    return l
```

Comment: I can't use a 'ready' functions.

Comment: Can you delete also isinstance?

Answer (score 0):

Other option using exceptions:

```
mylist = [1, 8, [6, 4, 8, 9], 1, [4, 6, 9, 0], 5, 6]

def recusum(mylist, total = 0):
  for x in mylist:
    try: total = recusum(x, total)
    except: total += x
  return total

recusum(mylist) #=> 67
```